# Passing data from listView to activity

Tags: android, json

In an Android App I have an activity with a listView.
The listView is populated from a JSON string.
I want to pass some of the JSON data from the selected row to another activity.
This is the current method:

```
private void showJSON(String json){
        ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
        pj.parseJSON();
        CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.nombres,ParseJSON.apellidos,ParseJSON.emails,ParseJSON.tels);
        listView.setAdapter(cl);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(Asesor.this, "Ha seleccionado el asesor -> "+ ParseJSON.nombres, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Asesor.this, WelcomeNoLogin.class);

                // Pass listview item click position
                i.putExtra("position", ParseJSON.nombres);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```

My issue is that I am getting strange values for the selected row data.

For example, if I select the second row, I get for ParseJSON.nombre the value Ljava.lang.string;@42197b8.
What should I change to get the real data?

EDITED:
ParseJSON.class

```
public class ParseJSON {
    public static String[] ids;
    public static String[] nombres;

    public static String[] apellidos;

    public static String[] tels;
    public static String[] emails;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NOMBRE = "nombre";

    public static final String KEY_TEL = "tel";

    public static final String KEY_APELLIDOS = "apellidos";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    private JSONArray users = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseJSON(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSON(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            ids = new String[users.length()];
            nombres = new String[users.length()];
            apellidos = new String[users.length()];
            tels = new String[users.length()];

            emails = new String[users.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
                nombres[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NOMBRE);
                apellidos[i] = jo.getString(KEY_APELLIDOS);
                tels[i] = jo.getString(KEY_TEL);

                emails[i] = jo.getString(KEY_EMAIL);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do u know ParseJSON.nombres what it contains?

Comment: @Raghavendra, yes, it is always a string

Comment: ParseJSON is this your custom class? can u post that class?

Comment: nombres is a String array

Comment: @mvasco u r trying to pass array not a single object

Comment: @Raghavendra, yes, sorry,

Comment: glad! Happy coding:)

Comment: @Raghavendra, the answer is ParseJSON.nombres[position]... thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing whole array object to intent. You have to pass the object of specific position, which you have clicked.

Following code will help you:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(Asesor.this, "Ha seleccionado el asesor -> "+  ParseJSON.nombres[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(Asesor.this, WelcomeNoLogin.class);

        // Pass listview item click position
        i.putExtra("position", ParseJSON.nombres[position]); /// update code here
        // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
        startActivity(i);
    }

});
```

Comment: there is no get method in array.

Comment: @mallaudin. yes earlier user haven't posted whole code so I thought it was list..

Comment: Thank you, I got the same answer

Comment: Yep. I tried to edit it, it said you should edit more than 6 characters

Answer (score 2):

`ParseJSON.nombres` is a **string array**. Use

```
i.putExtra("position", ParseJSON.nombres[position]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer. ParseJSON.nombres[position], not  ParseJSON.nombres.get[position]

Answer (score 1):

nombres is a string array. While fetching it from WelcomeNoLogin use intent.getStringArrayExtra, If not already.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @mvasco  sir is Right you are passing array not single object.
you can pass Single Object two way first pass object using bundle with serialization object or you can also use getter setter method